# Get Explorer's children in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, explorer

I created folder shortcuts [image: task bar shortcuts] for my taskbar and I would like them to stop launching a new explorer every time

[image: Multiple windows of the same folder in explorer]

So I decided to create a batch script, howover I can not get the kids from explorer.exe

[image: task manager]

```
@echo off
pushd
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq explorer.exe C:\Users\danil\Desktop\ISO" | find /i "explorer.exe C:\Users\danil\Desktop\ISO" > nul ||(start explorer.exe C:\Users\danil\Desktop\ISO)
```

Comment: Confused on how your image name is equal to **explorer.exe C:\Users\danil\Desktop\ISO**.

Comment: the explorer.exe windows are not seprarate processes so you will be not able to list them with tasklist.

Comment: What do you want to do with the all the windows that you want to list? You want to start the "folders" if there's not already opened one?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your attempt is that tasklist will list only one instance of `explorer.exe` but not the titles of each window openned.

With some edits over [this](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDesktopWindows) I've created [listWindows.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/listWindows.bat) - it will list all visible windows names and their coresponding executable. So you can try this:

```
 call listWindows.bat|findstr /i /b /e "explorer::Downloads" >nul 2>nul || (
    start "" explorer.exe "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads"
 )
```

To check the windows you need to start you can just try this:

```
call listWindows.bat|findstr /i /b  "explorer::"
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check the opening folders by checking the command line options, because the arguments stay the same across the whole lifetime of the process even after you changed to some other folders in that window. You need to use [scriptable shell objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776890(v=vs.85)) to get the current address.

Here's a PowerShell script to open a folder if it's not already opened in explorer

```powershell
$folder = 'C:\Users\danil\Desktop\ISO'
$folderOpened = $false
foreach ($w in (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()) {
    if ($w.LocationURL -ieq ([uri]$folder).AbsoluteUri) {
        $folderOpened = $true; break
    }
}
if (-not $folderOpened) { Invoke-Item $folder } # or start $folder
```

Below is an equivalent hybrid batch-jscript snippet

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
cscript //e:jscript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b

@end

// JScript Section

var objShell = new ActiveXObject("shell.application");
var objShellWindows;
objShellWindows = objShell.Windows();

if (objShellWindows != null)
{
    // the folder you want to open
    var folder = "file:///C:/Users/danil/Desktop/ISO";
    var folderOpened = 0;
    for (var objEnum = new Enumerator(objShellWindows);
             !objEnum.atEnd(); objEnum.moveNext())
    {
        if (folder == objEnum.item().LocationUrl)
        {
            folderOpened = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!folderOpened) // open the folder if it's not already opened
        objShell.Explore(folder); // or objshell.Open(folder)
}
```

Each explorer window is represented by an `InternetExplorer` object that can be retrieved from the [`Shell.Windows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shell-windows) collection. You need to use a [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) instead of a normal Windows path, but it works. Of course you can even further change it to switch to the folder window if it's being opened. You can also use VBS or any other languages that support scriptable shell objects

### Update:

You can avoid the file URI scheme by changing `objEnum.item().LocationUrl` to `objEnum.item().Document.Folder.Self.Path`

In the PowerShell version above it means changing

```
if ($w.LocationURL -ieq ([uri]$folder).AbsoluteUri) {
```

to

```
if ($w.Document.Folder.Self.Path -ieq $folder) {
```